# How to integrate PHP with yeoman angular project

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm using [yeoman](/questions/tagged/yeoman) project using [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) normally I know how to use angularjs with PHP on normal projects.

But I'm confused to use php with yeoman.

Where should I create `.php` file and how should I call `$http` scope in `main.js` controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using generator-angular, you need two elements:

1/ Have your PHP running as you would normally in a subdirectory like `public` so `public/index.php` is loaded when you go to `http://localhost/`

2/ Use a Grunt task to compile the individual AngularJS source files in `src` into a single file somewhere like `public/js/myapp.js` and in `public/index.php` add something like `<script src="/js/myapp.js></script>`

3/ If you're wanting to send JSON to your angular app, use `json_encode` such as:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($someArray); ?>
?>
```

You could also have a look at [grunt-php](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-php) for serving up you PHP files on a dev box.

Shameless self plug - I've also written a generator that creates a simple AngularJS app with a FlightPHP backend: https://npmjs.org/package/generator-flightangular - Which might give you an idea of how you can split the JavaScript elements from the PHP backend.

Answer (score 4):

You could use web service API calls to your PHP project. Usually `PHP` and `AngularJS` are two different scopes. We can establish communication between these two using API's. Normally it is better to use some `REST API` frameworks like Slim.

http://www.slimframework.com/